# Powershell Codewrap for repeat option and bug with form

Tags: forms, powershell

I got a script which is handling some things. I know a lot say I should get more short scripts which are working. But there are many people which can't handle many files or scripts and want 1 which can do all, and I can't tell 600 people which script does what. I need a kind of assembling at least of a few.

I wanted to make a workaround for the canceld options. The easiest way is to wrap all the code in a `do {} while ()` for sure. But are there any options where I can repeat a single option? Something like when it asks do you really want to cancel.

And a real annoying bug I can't fix is that after every single action the start form blops up again. I tried out diffrent ways to debug with a counter but it didn't count up and also I tried to put the function assembling at a other place didn't fix it as well. Don't know why it happens.

Code for repro

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Set-PSDebug -Strict #Errorcall if a variable isnt declared

#Function Assembling

function Saveat()
{
    #working
    $Saveat = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $Saveat.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    #IF selection is canceld
    $result = $form.ShowDialog()
    [void]$Saveat.ShowDialog()
    return $Saveat.FileName
}

function Compare($location1, $location2)
{
    #work in progress   
    $CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path $location1 -UseCulture
    $CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path $location2 -UseCulture
    $Compared = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CSV1 -DifferenceObject $CSV2 |
                select -ExpandProperty inputObject |
                sort
    [void] $CSV1
    [void] $CSV2
    return $Compared
}

function whichcsv()
{
    #working
    $location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $location.Filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $result = $form.ShowDialog()
    [void]$location.ShowDialog()
    return $location.FileName
}

#Select which option Form
#region Initiate Form  **This Form Blops up after every user action**

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "CSV Liste"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,195)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,195)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Welche CSV Liste soll geladen werden:"
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$listBox.Height = 150

[void] $listBox.Items.Add("List Filter")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADComputer")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("AS400 Personal Not implemented yet")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADBenutzer Not implemented yet")
#endregion

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    #Choosed Option
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem
    switch ($x)
    {
        #Option 1 working
        "List Filter"
        {
            #Select path of the CSV
            $csvpath = whichcsv

            #IF selection is canceld
            if ($csvpath -eq "")
            {
                Write-Host "Operation Canceld"
            }
            else 
            {
                #CSV Import and Filter set                
                $CSV = Import-Csv -Path $csvpath -UseCulture
                $Filter = Read-Host "Please enter columname. Leave clear for cancel"
                if ($Filter -eq "")
                {
                    Write-Host "Operation canceld"                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $y = $CSV | Select $Filter
                    Write-Host "CSV Successfull Imported and Filter set"
                }

                $SDestination = Saveat
                if ($SDestination -eq "")
                {
                    Write-Host "Operation Canceld"                
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Host "Process started"
                    foreach ($y1 in $y)
                    {
                        New-Object PSObject -Property @{Inventarnummer=$y1.$Filter} | Export-Csv $SDestination -NoTypeInformation -Append
                    }
                    Write-Host "Process finished"
                }
            }
        }

        #Option 2 working 
        "ADComputer" 
        {
            #Select path of the CSV
            $csvpath = whichcsv

            #IF selection is canceld
            if ($csvpath -eq "")
            {
                Write-Host "Operation Canceld"
            }
            else 
            {
                #CSV Import with filter
                $CSV = Import-Csv -Path $csvpath -Delimiter ',' 
                $Filter = Read-Host "Please enter columname. Leave clear for cancel"
                if ($Filter -eq "")
                {
                    Write-Host "Operation canceld"                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $y = $CSV | Select $Filter
                    Write-Host "CSV Successfull Imported and Filter set"
                }

                #Path selection
                $Saveworking = Saveat
                $SaveFailed = Saveat

                if($Saveworking -eq "")
                {
                    Write-Host "Operation canceld"
                }
                elseif ($SaveFailed -eq "")
                {
                    Write-Host "Operation canceld"
                }
                else
                {
                    #Progress
                    Write-Host "Process Start"
                    foreach($n in $y)
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            $Computer = [system.net.dns]::resolve($n.$Filter) | Select HostName,AddressList
                            $IP = ($Computer.AddressList).IPAddressToString
                            Write-Host $n.$Filter $IP
                            New-Object PSObject -Property @{IPAddress=$IP; Name=$n.$Filter} | Export-Csv $Saveworking -NoTypeInformation -Append
                        } 
                        catch 
                        {
                            Write-Host "$($n.$Filter) is unreachable."
                            New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name=$n.$Filter} | Export-Csv $SaveFailed -NoTypeInformation -Append
                        }
                    }
                    Write-Host "Process successfull completed"
                }
            }
        }

        #Option 3 Not implemented yet
        "AS400 Personal Not implemented yet" 
        {
            Write-Host "Not implemented yet"
        }

        #Option 4 not implemented yet
        "ADBenutzer Not implemented yet" 
        {
            Write-Host "Not implemented yet"
        }  
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Operation Canceld"
}
```

Comment: Don't `$form.ShowDialog()` when you don't want to `$form.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: But without the $form.ShowDialog() those windows never would open

Comment: Ok after passing through once more i got what you meant... i got still some of the Show this form left in the functions itself. Well thx for the advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to work with [form events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `.DialogResult`.
For the **`Cancel`** button you would probably do something like: `$CancelButton.Add_Click({[Void]$Form.Window.Close()})`
For the **`OK`** button you would probably want to put the majority of your `OK` task in a function and invoke it from a similar event:

```
Function Task {
    #Choosed Option
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem
    switch ($x)
    {
        #Option 1 working
        "List Filter"
        {
            #Select path of the CSV
            $csvpath = whichcsv
            ...
```

---

```
$OkButton.Add_Click({Task})
```

(And close the dialog (`[Void]$Form.Window.Close()`) when the task is completed)

Comment: Can you give me a little example? As I never worked so far with those events i don't really know how to code it

Comment: `$CancelButton.Add_Click({[Void]$Form.Window.Close()})` is the little example. Add this to you form and click the cancel button to see the result. And as described, for the OK button, put everything in a function and call the function by adding it to the click event: `$OkButton.Add_Click({Task})`